# Android Push FCM Как при клике на уведомления открыть activity

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления

Как при клике на уведомления (Notification) запустить нужное activity даже если приложение не запущенно?

Вот мой отображения уведомления:

```
private void sendNotification(String url_post, String thumb_post, String message_title, String message_body) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SinglePostActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("_post_url", url_post);
    intent.putExtra("_post_title", message_body);
    intent.putExtra("_toolbar_title", message_body);
    intent.putExtra("_toolbar_thumb", thumb_post);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.beloweb_icon_small)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(message_title)
            .setContentText(message_body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 600, 500, 600})
            .setLights(Color.GREEN, 400, 400)
            .setTicker(message_body);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: Ваша проблема не понятна. Что именно у вас не получается? У вас запускается SinglePostActivity, а вы хотите другую активити и не можете заменить SinglePostActivity на имя другого класса?

Comment: Нет я нажимаю на уведомления и вместо SinglePostActivity запускается MainActivity. А когда приложение работает и пришло уведомления то открывается SinglePostActivity. Мне нужно сделать так например приложение установлено но не открыть тут приходит уведомления и при клике должно открыться приложения и сразу запуститься SinglePostActivity а не MainActivity

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37560009/3212712) - возможно вам надо в FireBase настроить какую именно актвити надо открывать, а также настроить intentFilter в манифесте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37567208/3212712) вам надо указать в FireBase, при создании уведомления click_action с к-л значением, кое должно быть идентичным `IntentFilter` целевой активити

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "XXX",
    ...
  ],
  "data": {
    "id_offer": "41"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "This is the Title",
    "text": "Hello I'm a notification",
    "icon": "ic_push",
    "click_action": "ACTIVITY_XPTO"
  }
}
```

В манифесте указываем это в фильтр

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityXPTO"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTIVITY_XPTO" />        
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```